# Overriding values with css specifity or always being specific - best practice?

Tags: css

This is simply a question of whether it is better practice to have a default value for a base class, which is overwritten with css specificity rules, or whether it's better to not ever apply the original css in cases where it is not wanted.

What is best practice? Are there consequences in terms of load times in the browser?

Example of default value, overwritten with css specificity rule:

```
.button {
    ...
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 1em 1.5em 1em 1.5em;
    &.small {
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
    }
}
```

Example of only applying the css when it is intended to be used:

```
.button {
    ...
    &:not(.small) {
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 1em 1.5em 1em 1.5em;
    }
    &.small {
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that totally depends on your opinion of what you'd prefer. In your example I would probably rely on override only since you aren't applying any new rules in the `.small` button. But if the examples get far more complex with a lot more nested rules, you might want to go with option 2 to prevent styles from leaking.

Comment: Is there any performance effect on the browser in applying the `:not(.small)` class versus overwriting the default `.button` properties?

Comment: There would be, but probably not enough to matter. You can read a bit about there here: https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/